# VSCode remove multiline comment shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, shortcut

Let's say that I have

```
/*
* comment 1
* comment 2
*/
```

in my VSCode. What is the shortcut to uncomment?

I tried block comment shortcut but doesn't work well

```
/*
* .......
*/

becomes

* .......
```

Comment: Look at your Keyboard Shortcuts for block comment.

Comment: How did you get those `*`'s before the text in your block comment?  Those are not automatically added for me.  And what language are you using?

Comment: I'm using javascript with eslint rules for comments (multiline-comment-style: "starred-block")

Answer (score 0):

Select the text that is commented out with /* and */ characters, and then press `Ctrl+Shift+A`.

Answer (score -1):

`Shift`+`Alt`+`A` works like charming.

Here you can find all the keyboard shortcuts.

[All VSCode Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

PS: I prefer `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`/` for toggling block comments because `Ctrl`+`/` is shortcut for toggling line comments so it's east to remember.

To do so, in VSCode just click on the

> settings

icon in the bottom left of the screen and click

> Keyboard Shortcuts

and find "**toggle block...**". Then click and enter your desired combination.

`Ctrl`+`K`, `Ctrl`+`U` removes the `//` comments

Comment: That is for toggling line comments, not multiline comments.